# How to render the same fetched raster tile across different zoom levels on a mapbox-gl-js map

Tags: typescript, next.js, raster, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I have a simple Mapbox-gl-js map with a raster layer rendered onto it. The raster layer fetches tiles using the xyz request scheme from an external server. I am giving a transformRequest callback to the Map object to intercept requests to that server and transform the url. The callback takes the url and if it is odd, rounds down the z (zoom level) to the closest even number. For example, `<host>/tiles/3/5/12.png` would become `<host>/tiles/2/5/12@2x.png` or `<host>/tiles/7/13/2@2x.png` would become `<host>/tiles/6/13/2@2x.png`.

The problem I am having is that the tiles disappear when the map is at an odd zoom level. This occurs even if the same tile I am fetching normally renders when the map is at an even zoom level. So if I am fetching a zoom 4 tile on map zoom 4, they render normal but if I am fetching a zoom 4 tile on map zoom 3, they do not. Do any one of you mapping gurus have some insight on why this may be occurring?

Here's the function I am using to transform the url. It catches tiles going to radar-global and transforms the zoom level in the url.

```
// app.tsx
const map = new Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    transformRequest: transformRequestFunc,
});

// utils.ts
export const transformRequestFunc = (url: any, resourceType: any) => {
    if (resourceType === 'Tile' && url.indexOf('radar-global') > -1) {
        const regex = new RegExp('[0-9][0-9]?(?=(/[0-9][0-9]?/[0-9][0-9]?/(\\d{10}@2x.png)))')
        const zoom = url.match(regex)[0]
        const zoomStr = (2 * Math.round(zoom / 2)).toString()
        return {
            url: url.replace(regex,zoomStr)
        };
    }
};
```